# An internal error occurred during: "Enable SonarLint on all projects". Unable to add builder

Tags: sonarlint, sonarlint-eclipse

When starting Eclipse in a workspace, SonarLint plugin reports the following error:

> An internal error occurred during: "Enable SonarLint on all projects".
>   Unable to add builder

After confirming the errmsg, both Eclipse and SonarLint plugin work properly.

Nevertheless, the message is misleading. What causes it? In my workspace, some projects are open and some not.

Answer (score 2):

For me issue was coming due to lombok jar so Need to upgrade LOMBOK  version to 1.18.12 in sts and in pom.xml both and it got resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by one of my project being read-only.
For some reason, SonarLint defines a global Eclipse job, to add itself to every project that is open. If the process fails, you get that annoying message.

As a workaround I've removed a read-only flag from the .project files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to update the latest Lombok jar in either STS or eclipse, this will resolve the issue for me. And you need a sonar lint plugin for the eclipse for sure.

[image]

The attached screenshot is coming in my case, but after updating the Lombok jar it is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Latest lomlok version and it got solved.
I replace the old lomlok file with latest version from https://projectlombok.org/download.

Answer (score 0):

I am using lombok 1.18.4 and eclipse = eclipse-java-12-R-win32-x86-64.

Project is compiled and able to run the project but in eclipse whenever i am opening any java file facing issue :
An internal error occurred during: "SonarLint processing file  lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$ValPortal /server/com/EmployeeList.java".
lombok/launch/PatchFixesHider$ValPortal
[Sonar lint issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVHuz.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This propblem was resolved with next version of LOMBOK.
Upgread to 1.12 or higher version and rebuild pom.xlm
I was upgread to 1.20 and problem dispaired ;)